# Accessing a server without joining the Domain

Tags: windows

I want to access a folder in the server, but if I try to access to the folder without joining the domain, every time when I restart the system, it asks for username and password

Is there any way to avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify with OS you are using. If you use Windows since Windows XP there is an option to Map a Network Drive specifying the accessing credentials and enabling the possibility to connect automatically at login.

This is a screenshot of Windows 8, but apart the graphic the other Windows versions are the same.

[image]

Comment: Addition to Drake's answer: When you connect using different credentials, and entering the credentials (especially against a domain-server) you need to put your username using the domain prefix eg. DOMAIN\username and password for that username.